# Optio and Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Using Adobe Acrobat 9 Pro (previously using Adobe 7 Pro) to cut down PDF files by extracting only certain pages from the document.  Due to compression settings that are apparetnly inherent in AA9Pro, the cut down file will not work in Optio.  How do I remove the compression feature (and any other formatting 'features') so that the cut down file properties are no different than the original file?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried Document/Split Document and that works for me.  The Extract Pages does not work nor does the distiller/printer.

Comment: I tried this - but Split Document does not let me get pages 12 - 18 of a 45 page document.  I need to be able to extract certain pages.